# how do I change the button color in js?

Tags: javascript

This is my code it is called when a button is clicked in html I dont know why the button is not going black/white Actually it worked just fine before I put my php code in my html file The alert with "asdf" is just to check if my code executing or not

function checkp(event){

```
var x=event.currentTarget;
var button_type=document.getElementsByTagName("button");   

for(var i=0;i<button_type.length;i++)
    {
        if(button_type[i].id==x.id){
    //  alert(button_type[i].id);
            var index=i;
        }

     }
        var start=0;
        var end=button_type.length;

        for(var q=start;q<=end;q++)
            {
                if(q==index)
                    {       alert("asdf");
                            button_type[q].style.filter="grayscale(0)";
                            button_type[q].style.padding="3cm";
                    }

            else{
                            button_type[q].style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
                            button_type[q].style.padding="";

                }
            }
    }
```

This is how my buttons are declared in html

```
    <button  id ="love" type="button" ><img src="love.png"  alt="notfound"  width="30" height="30"/></button>

    <button  id ="haha" type="button" ><img src="haha.png"  alt="notfound"  width="30" height="30"/>  </button>
    <button  id ="wow"  type="button" ><img src="wow.jpg"  alt="notfound"  width="30" height="30"/>  </button>
    <button  id ="Angry"type="button" ><img src="angry.png"  alt="notfound"  width="30" height="30"/> </button>
    <button  id ="sad"  type="button" ><img src="sad.png"   alt="notfound" width="30" height="30"/>    </button>






     and this is how I called the js function
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var v=0;v<x.length;v++)
    {
         x[v].addEventListener("click",checkp,false);
      }
```

Comment: Where's `index` defined?, try declaring it outside your first `for`.

Comment: maybe it's `event.target` instead of `event.currentTarget`?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share the html?

Does the ID of each of your buttons start from 0 and increment by 1?

If not, then there is an error with this line as id = "" and not a number.

```
LINE 6: if(button_type[i].id==x.id){
```

What are you trying to achieve with this code? If you tell us what you want it to do with some html then i can definitely help!

Comment: Here's my html code but the file is .php  because I had to use some php code basically what I am trying is it is mock up blogging site In this html all the posts stored in my database are displayed and for each post I need to have six rections which a user can select each user can only have a single reaction for post